# When questions are merged, are the answers merged too?

Tags: bug, merged-questions

This is an example where two questions were merged, but all the answers from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678997/looking-for-urbanspoon-api (Looking for Urbanspoon API) were removed when merged here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498150/urbanspoon-api-information.

Is that by intent or a bug? The [tag merged questions] indicates that answers should be merged,

> When questions are merged, both questions are retained (one will just
>   be a stub) and all answers are migrated into the merged question.

Also, the dates don't make sense. The merge was supposedly done in November 2011, but I was still seeing the question, and getting up votes for my answer, in 2013 and 2014.

[image: screen shot from my SO account dashboard]

Comment: Really can't see any issue here. Answers are indeed moved to the merge destination and you got to keep the reputation even though the question was deleted back in October 13 2014 since it had score bigger than 3. No point leaving a stub leading to a deleted question, thus BoltClock removed it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's intentional. The whole point of merging questions is to consolidate all answers into one single location. The duplicate question is left as a stub pointing directly to the merge target so the reader wastes no time reaching the question where all the answers now reside.

In this case, the merge target itself was recently removed, taking your answer with it, because the question is off-topic. There is no sense in keeping the stub around, so I'm going to remove it as well.

Comment: See my edit please. That isn't what is happening.

Comment: Now that you removed both questions, there's no way to show what I meant!

Comment: You just removed the merge target "recently removed" one minute ago, AFTER I asked the question!

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman: The merge was done in 2011, and the original question was deleted in 2014. How does it not add up?

Comment: Sigh, no! The merge was done in 2011 supposedly, but that's wrong! None of the answers were moved! Look at the question you just deleted. I can't now, as I'm not an admin. I don't care about the rep points. You, well, SE platform, has a bug.

Comment: @EllieKesselman no bug here, you just fail to realize how the system works.

Comment: @Ellie What gives you that impression? The question [Urbanspoon API Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498150/urbanspoon-api-information) has 0 answers on it, because it was merged into [Looking for Urbanspoon API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678997/looking-for-urbanspoon-api), which has 4 answers including your +8 answer. The second one was deleted Oct 13 '14 because it was a blatantly off-topic question. No one ever deleted the merge stub, though, so it was still sitting around pointing to a deleted question.

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman: I really don't see the problem. The question I just deleted was "Urbanspoon API Information". That was the stub. "Looking for Urbanspoon API" was the original. Your screenshot shows the title for which your answer continued receiving upvotes being the original title.

Comment: How then could I get up vote points in 2013-2014 if my answer were deleted in 2011?

Comment: The original was removed in 2014. Check the edit log.

Comment: This: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248379/when-questions-are-merged-are-the-answers-merged-too/248380?noredirect=1#comment813545_248380 Yes! That is what I mean! How can that happen? "No one ever deleted the merge stub, though, so it was still sitting around pointing to a deleted question."

Comment: @EllieKesselman The question was *merged* in 2011, not deleted. A merge completely changes the post ID associated with your answer. It doesn't delete it on the original and recreate it on the new one. It acts as if your answer never existed on the original and always existed on the target. The target question didn't get deleted until 2014.